# How to specify an arbitrary dummy variable contrast in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I know that R automatically creates dummy variables from categorical values, but it also automatically chooses the reference value (I think alphabetically?). How do I specify a different value to be the reference without changing the names of the values? I realize I could probably relabel the factors a,b,c... in the order I prefer, but that seems kind of kludgey to me.

Just to be clear, I'll make up an example. Let's say the factor is **color** and the values are *red*, *blue*, *green*, and *yellow*.

```
mod.lm <- lm(preference ~ color, data = flowers)
```

The intercept in this case would be for the case **color** = *blue*, but I want to make it *yellow*. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `relevel`:

```
  # In this case, the reference category is setosa
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)
summary(model) 

# Now I want Virginica to be the reference category
iris$Species <- relevel(iris$Species, ref='virginica')
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)
summary(model)
```

In your case it could be

```
flowers$color <- relevel(flowers$color, ref='yellow')
lm(preference ~ color, data = flowers)
```

And this model will give you the estimation using as the ref category '`yellow`'